# Play Console - Closed Testing with Google Groups Email...Fail

Tags: google-play-console, google-groups

We have a custom B2B app that the customer would like now to distribute privately to their contractors in addition to their current EMM process for internal staff. As we understand there are no options provided through the Play Console for private apps in a production environment relying on sideloading only and all it's issues. An alternative suggested by many on SO is to run a closed testing track by invite. We accept it is a poor workaround but at this stage we are not aware of other options.

The organisation deploying the app has a G Workspace using their own domain and have created a G Group for contractors with "Allow members outside your organisation" enabled. The idea being that the G Group can be added to the closed track testers in the Play Console (using the G Group option) and the organisation can then add their contractors to the group as needed.

The G Group is running fine and members can see the group and post as needed. The G Group email however is not recognised by the Play Console even after 24 hours (see ***example*** below). The group email uses the organisation's domain (eg group_email@org_domain.com) as required in the group set up from the admin console rather than the standard group_email@googlegroups.com. Testing with other public group emails work fine.

We have submitted requests unsuccessfully to Google over the past month about options here so are wondering now if the above scenario is in fact technically valid and if there is something we are missing to get this going?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After more testing it seems whilst the concept is valid, Google Groups created within GSuite, regardless of whether "Allow members outside your organisation" is enabled, cannot be used for testing releases in the Play Store where your organisation domain is used.

Instead when creating a group from within a GSuite account ensure to use @googlegroups.com in the options for the group email.

Comment: thank you for sharing your solution. Please, can you share how you managed to create a googlegroups.com using the gsuite account? I did create the googlegroups.com and it work fine using my personal e-mail, but in my case I need this googlegroups.com to be associated with the organization and not with a personal e-mail.